# Using Left Join in 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to join 3 tables using LEFT JOIN, but I always have an error. Please help me.

Thank you

The output that I want:

```
Name            Date              Open               Close
POS             01/01/2014         4                  10
ONE             01/02/2014         6                  5
...
...
...
```

My query:

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) --as cnt_opened
||','||NVL(c.CNT_CLOSED,0) --as cnt_closed
||','||q.NAME
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE d
LEFT JOIN APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE q
ON t.queue_id = q.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME) AS report_date,count(*) AS cnt_opened
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME)
) o ON d.DTIME_DAY=o.REPORT_DATE
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME) as report_date,count(*) AS cnt_closed
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
WHERE t.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME)
) c ON D.DTIME_DAY=c.REPORT_DATE
WHERE d.DTIME_DAY BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1
AND d.DTIME_DAY = TRUNC(d.DTIME_DAY)
AND TRUNC(d.DTIME_DAY)= d.DTIME_DAY
ORDER BY D.DTIME_DAY;
```

Comment: Remove the `;` in line 8 and try `ON t.queue_id = q.id`

Comment: Any verbiage with your error?

Comment: ORA-00904: "T"."QUEUE_ID": invalid identifier @wruckie

Comment: I already remove the ; in my query, still i have an error @Dba

Comment: That's because you need to declare a table in FROM clause before trying to use it in the JOIN conditions.

Comment: I already declare a table @vishad

Comment: Before you use the condition "ON t.queue_id = q.id". You need to declare a table aliased 't' in the FROM clause. @user3098728

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any table alias for "t" in your first left join. So oracle doesn't know what is the "t" in `t.queue_id` yet at the join condition

`ON t.queue_id = q.id`.

from  your code:

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||NVL(o.CNT_OPENED,0) --as cnt_opened
||','||NVL(c.CNT_CLOSED,0) --as cnt_closed
||','||q.NAME
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE d
LEFT JOIN APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE q
ON t.queue_id = q.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME) AS report_date,count(*) AS cnt_opened
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME)
)
```

the alias "t" is defined inside the block :

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME) AS report_date,count(*) AS cnt_opened
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME)
)
```

Now, as the join `ON t.queue_id = q.id` is otside this block (outside the brackets), the alias "t" is not available at that point.

hence the error.

Comment: i put LEFT JOIN APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE q
ON t.queue_id = q.id after LEFT JOIN (
SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME) AS report_date,count(*) AS cnt_opened
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -120 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME)
) o ON d.DTIME_DAY=o.REPORT_DATE but i have an error still

Comment: I have further explained my answer. hope you get the point.
Is the query written by you or someone else? Because if you have, then I suspect you need to understand some basic ideas of Scoping in programming first.